# How to get all permutations of groups in a string?

Tags: c#, pseudocode

This is **not** homework, although it may seem like it. I've been browsing through the UK Computing Olympiad's website and found this problem (Question 1): [here](http://olympiad.org.uk/papers/2015/bio/bio15-exam.pdf). I was baffled by it, and I'd want to see what you guys thought of how to do it. I can't think of any neat ways to get everything into groups (checking whether it's a palindrome after that is simple enough, i.e. `originalString == new String(groupedString.Reverse.SelectMany(c => c).ToArray)`, assuming it is a char array).

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Text for those at work:**

---

> A palindrome is a word that shows the same sequence of letters when
>   reversed. If a word can have its letters grouped together in two or
>   more blocks (each containing one or more adjacent letters) then it is
>   a block palindrome if reversing the order of those blocks results in
>   the same sequence of blocks.
>
> For example, using brackets to indicate blocks, the following are
>   block palindromes:
>
> • BONBON can be grouped together as (BON)(BON);
>
> • ONION can be grouped together as (ON)(I)(ON);
>
> • BBACBB can be grouped together as (B)(BACB)(B) or (BB)(AC)(BB) or
>   (B)(B)(AC)(B)(B)
>
> Note that (BB)(AC)(B)(B) is not valid as the reverse (B)(B)(AC)(BB)
>   shows the blocks in a different order.

And the question is essentially how to generate all of those groups, to then check whether they are palindromes!

Comment: Now then, how is it unclear what I'm asking? If you can read the link the question is actually stand-alone, and I'm just giving extra detail.

Comment: I'm at work and can't view that site. Question's pretty unclear, to me!

Comment: @sab669 Edited the text in for clarity!

Comment: Not the most efficient one, but I think you can read a character from beginning and store it in string, then read one from the end and store it in another string and so on. If you found them equal, that's a pair. (For second strong we need to add the characters to the beginning of string)

Comment: @HoomanYar That seems like a pretty good idea! I'll try that for sure, but how would you be able to get more than one answer with that?

Comment: You'd need to start by comparing the first letter of the string with the last. Then the first two with the last two, and the first *n* with the last *n*, until you find matching substrings.

Comment: If it's a match store it in an array and move to next character and store it along with other characters in those strings,. Sorry for not writing the code since I'm in class now. Im gonna add it as the answer later

Comment: You should submit this as a CodeGolf challenge.

Comment: @HoomanYar Yeah, I got the idea of the solution, but that would give you one of the possible solutions, not all of them! For example, for BBACBB it would give you (B)(B)(AC)(B)(B) and not the alternatives, such as (BB)(AC)(BB) or (B)(BACB)(B)

Comment: @BradleyUffner Sounds like a good idea, actually!

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Alright, I was thinking about this. Here is the solution: if you got a match, check the same thing for that match. So you'll get (B)(BACB)(B) AND (BB)(AC)(BB) , then we check the second match (BB) and with get (B)(B). this can be done in one loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
   public List<string> BlockPalin(string s) {
        var list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= s.Length / 2; i++) {
            int backInx = s.Length - i;
            if (s.Substring(0, i) == s.Substring(backInx, i)) {
                var result = string.Format("({0})", s.Substring(0, i));
                result += "|" + result;

                var rest = s.Substring(i, backInx - i);

                if (rest == string.Empty) {
                    list.Add(result.Replace("|", rest));
                    return list;
                }
                else if (rest.Length == 1) {
                    list.Add(result.Replace("|", string.Format("({0})", rest)));
                    return list;
                }
                else {
                    list.Add(result.Replace("|", string.Format("({0})", rest)));

                    var recursiveList = BlockPalin(rest);
                    if (recursiveList.Count > 0) {
                        foreach (var recursiveResult in recursiveList) {
                            list.Add(result.Replace("|", recursiveResult));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                    //EDIT: Thx to @juharr this list.Add is not needed...
                    //    list.Add(result.Replace("|",string.Format("({0})",rest)));
                        return list;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```

And call it like this (EDIT: Again thx to @juharr, the distinct is not needed):

```
        var x = BlockPalin("BONBON");//.Distinct().ToList();
        var y = BlockPalin("ONION");//.Distinct().ToList();
        var z = BlockPalin("BBACBB");//.Distinct().ToList();
```

The result:

- x contains 1 element: (BON)(BON)
- y contains 1 element: (ON)(I)(ON)
- z contains 3 elements: (B)(BACB)(B),(B)(B)(AC)(B)(B) and (BB)(AC)(BB)

Comment: This works! Now to try and understand the code, haha! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @It'sNotALie. The idea is quite simple: Pick the same count of characters from left and right and increase the count until you've found something that matches. Push the rest (the sub-string between the matching parts) recursively into the same process... until the rest is empty or of length 1. If the recursive call comes back with no result, just take the full sub-string as final middle-group. That's it :-)

Comment: If you remove the `list.Add(result.Replace("|", string.Format("({0})", rest)));` in the last `else` you won't get duplicates.

Answer (score 9):

> And the question is essentially how to generate all of those groups, to then check whether they are palindromes!

I note that this is not necessarily the best strategy. Generating all the groups first and then checking to see if they are palidromes is considerably more inefficient than *generating only those groups which are palindromes*.

But in the spirit of answering the question asked, let's solve the problem recursively. I will just generate all the groups; checking whether a set of groups is a palindrome is left as an exercise. I am also going to ignore the requirement that a set of groups contains at least two elements; that is easily checked.

The way to solve this problem elegantly is to reason recursively. As with all recursive solutions, we begin with a trivial base case:

How many groupings are there of the empty string?  There is only the empty grouping; that is, the grouping with no elements in it.

Now we assume that we have a solution to a smaller problem, and ask "if we had a solution to a smaller problem, how could we use that solution to solve a larger problem?"

OK, suppose we have a larger problem. We have a string with 6 characters in it and we wish to produce all the groupings. Moreover, the groupings are symmetrical; the first group is the same size as the last group. By assumption we know how to solve the problem for any smaller string.

We solve the problem as follows. Suppose the string is ABCDEF.  We peel off A and F from both ends, we solve the problem for BCDE, which remember we know how to do by assumption, and now we prepend A and append F to each of those solutions.

The solutions for BCDE are `(B)(C)(D)(E), (B)(CD)(E), (BC)(DE), (BCDE)`. Again, *we assume as our inductive hypothesis that we have the solution to the smaller problem*.  We then combine those with A and F to produce the solutions for ABCDEF:  `(A)(B)(C)(D)(E)(F), (A)(B)(CD)(E)(F), (A)(BC)(DE)(F)` and `(A)(BCDE)(F)`.

We've made good progress. Are we done?  No. Next we peel off AB and EF, and recursively solve the problem for CD.  I won't labour how that is done. Are we done? No. We peel off ABC and DEF and recursively solve the problem for the empty string in the middle. Are we done? No. (ABCDEF) is also a solution. Now we're done.

I hope that sketch motivates the solution, which is now straightforward. We begin with a helper function:

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> AffixSequence<T>(T first, IEnumerable<T> body, T last)
    {
        yield return first;
        foreach (T item in body)
            yield return item;
        yield return last;
    }
```

That should be easy to understand. Now we do the real work:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> GenerateBlocks(string s)
    {

        // The base case is trivial: the blocks of the empty string 
        // is the empty set of blocks.
        if (s.Length == 0)
        {
            yield return new string[0];
            yield break;
        }
        // Generate all the sequences for the middle;
        // combine them with all possible prefixes and suffixes.
        for (int i = 1; s.Length >= 2 * i; ++i)
        {
            string prefix = s.Substring(0, i);
            string suffix = s.Substring(s.Length - i, i);
            string middle = s.Substring(i, s.Length - 2 * i);
            foreach (var body in GenerateBlocks(middle))
                yield return AffixSequence(prefix, body, suffix);
        }
        // Finally, the set of blocks that contains only this string
        // is a solution.
        yield return new[] { s };
    }
```

Let's test it.

```
        foreach (var blocks in GenerateBlocks("ABCDEF"))
            Console.WriteLine($"({string.Join(")(", blocks)})");
```

The output is

```
(A)(B)(C)(D)(E)(F)
(A)(B)(CD)(E)(F)
(A)(BC)(DE)(F)
(A)(BCDE)(F)
(AB)(C)(D)(EF)
(AB)(CD)(EF)
(ABC)(DEF)
(ABCDEF)
```

So there you go.

You could now check to see whether each grouping is a palindrome, but why?  The algorithm presented above can be easily modified to eliminate all non-palindromes by simply not recursing if the prefix and suffix are unequal:

```
if (prefix != suffix) continue;
```

The algorithm now enumerates only block palindromes. Let's test it:

```
        foreach (var blocks in GenerateBlocks("BBACBB"))
            Console.WriteLine($"({string.Join(")(", blocks)})");
```

The output is below; again, note that I am not filtering out the "entire string" block but doing so is straightforward.

```
(B)(B)(AC)(B)(B)
(B)(BACB)(B)
(BB)(AC)(BB)
(BBACBB)
```

If this subject interests you, consider reading my series of articles on using this same technique to generate every possible tree topology and every possible string in a language. It starts here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/19/every-binary-tree-there-is.aspx

Comment: I think you fell into @It'sNotALie. 's [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) You start with citing the sentence "... how to generate all of these groups ...". But this is not necessary. The OP **thought** it would be needed to find the groups first and check for matches than, but it is much easier to check for matches first and define the groupings around the matches you found. Your grouping algo is great, but does not really help to solve the problem...

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit about breaking the recursion if not a palindrom. This is the same concept several answers come up with: Find matches from left and right and go into recursion with the middle part. +1 from my side

Comment: @Shnugo: First, I noted exactly that in my first paragraph. Second, the modification to my algorithm to enumerate only palindromes is a single simple line which I noted in the last paragraph. I think this solution is pretty elegant.

Comment: Pretty elegant... yes, that's why I ticked the up-vote :-)

Answer (score 2):

Although not so elegant as the one provided by @Eric Lippert, one might find interesting the following iterative string allocation free solution:

```
struct Range
{
    public int Start, End;
    public int Length { get { return End - Start; } }
    public Range(int start, int length) { Start = start; End = start + length; }
}

static IEnumerable<Range[]> GetPalindromeBlocks(string input)
{
    int maxLength = input.Length / 2;
    var ranges = new Range[maxLength];
    int count = 0;
    for (var range = new Range(0, 1); ; range.End++)
    {
        if (range.End <= maxLength)
        {
            if (!IsPalindromeBlock(input, range)) continue;
            ranges[count++] = range;
            range.Start = range.End;
        }
        else
        {
            if (count == 0) break;
            yield return GenerateResult(input, ranges, count);
            range = ranges[--count];
        }
    }
}

static bool IsPalindromeBlock(string input, Range range)
{
    return string.Compare(input, range.Start, input, input.Length - range.End, range.Length) == 0;
}

static Range[] GenerateResult(string input, Range[] ranges, int count)
{
    var last = ranges[count - 1];
    int midLength = input.Length - 2 * last.End;
    var result = new Range[2 * count + (midLength > 0 ? 1 : 0)];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var range = result[i] = ranges[i];
        result[result.Length - 1 - i] = new Range(input.Length - range.End, range.Length);
    }
    if (midLength > 0)
        result[count] = new Range(last.End, midLength);
    return result;
}
```

Test:

```
foreach (var input in new [] { "BONBON", "ONION", "BBACBB" })
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    var blocks = GetPalindromeBlocks(input);
    foreach (var blockList in blocks)
        Console.WriteLine(string.Concat(blockList.Select(range => "(" + input.Substring(range.Start, range.Length) + ")")));
}
```

Removing the line `if (!IsPalindromeBlock(input, range)) continue;` will produce the answer to the OP question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear if you want *all* possible groupings, or just *a* possible grouping. This is one way, off the top-of-my-head, that you might get *a* grouping:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetBlocks(string testString)
{
    if (testString.Length == 0)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    int mid = testString.Length / 2;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < mid)
    {
        if (testString.Take(i + 1).SequenceEqual(testString.Skip(testString.Length - (i + 1))))
        {
            yield return new String(testString.Take(i+1).ToArray());
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (i == mid)
    {
        yield return testString;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var block in GetBlocks(new String(testString.Skip(i + 1).Take(testString.Length - (i + 1) * 2).ToArray())))
        {
            yield return block;
        }
    }
}
```

If you give it `bonbon`, it'll return `bon`. If you give it `onion` it'll give you back `on`, `i`. If you give it `bbacbb`, it'll give you `b`,`b`,`ac`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution (didn't have VS so I did it using java):

```
int matches = 0;
public void findMatch(String pal) {     
        String st1 = "", st2 = "";
        int l = pal.length() - 1;   
        for (int i = 0; i < (pal.length())/2 ; i ++ ) {
            st1 = st1 + pal.charAt(i);
            st2 = pal.charAt(l) + st2;
            if (st1.equals(st2)) {
                matches++;
                // DO THE SAME THING FOR THE MATCH
                findMatch(st1);
            }
            l--;
        }   
    }
```

The logic is pretty simple. I made two array of characters and compare them to find a match in each step. The key is you need to check the same thing for each match too.

```
findMatch("bonbon"); // 1
findMatch("bbacbb"); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this for BONBON...

```
string bonBon = "BONBON";
```

First check character count for even or odd.

```
bool isEven = bonBon.Length % 2 == 0;
```

Now, if it is even, split the string in half.

```
if (isEven)
{
   int halfInd = bonBon.Length / 2;
   string firstHalf = bonBon.Substring(0, halfInd );
   string secondHalf = bonBon.Substring(halfInd);
}
```

Now, if it is odd, split the string into 3 string.

```
else
{
   int halfInd = (bonBon.Length - 1) / 2;
   string firstHalf = bonBon.Substring(0, halfInd);
   string middle = bonBon.Substring(halfInd, bonBon.Length - halfInd);
   string secondHalf = bonBon.Substring(firstHalf.Length + middle.length);
}
```

May not be exactly correct, but it's a start....
Still have to add checking if it is actually a palindrome...
Good luck!!